# Htaccess - get last word of url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to implement a .htaccess redirect based on the following pattern:

```
www.site.com/ugly-depreciated-values-name
```

to

```
www.site.com/location/name
```

- The value after the final hyphen will always be used as the new url.
- There is not a constant number of hyphens in the old urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+-(.*)$ http://www.example.com/location/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     import re
     x="www.site.com/ugly-depreciated-values-name"
     print re.sub(r"(.*?/).*?-(\w+)$",r"\1location/\2",x)
```

Output:www.site.com/location/name

This is in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.+?-([^/-]+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```